# Best way to crop a letter on the image in python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

i am working on OCR as a part of my research . I want to crop a letter from the image such that each crop image should have one character only , i have cropped the multiple letters from the images but they are overlapping each other .

this is the kind of image i have [image]

this is the code i have written for cropping letter

```
for image in os.listdir("ab"):
    image_path = os.path.join("ab", image)
    img = Image.open(image_path)
    for j in range(30, 181, 30):
        ct += 1
        character_path = os.path.join("x-chars", str(ct) + ".png")
        ch = img.crop((j-50, 30, j, 50)) #here i am getting problem 
        ch.save(character_path)
```

Comment: I will recommend using a connected algorithm, to segment the 'larger' objects on your image. Once you have segmented your image, you could attempt OCR on the individual images. This [source](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/tutorial_segmentation.html) might be of help!

Comment: @EnriqueBet I have tried with Canny and Edge based segmentation but that doesnot helped me much.. that is why i started again from basics

Answer (score 0):

I updated the solution to work on Python 3.7

```py
import sys,os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from skimage import measure
try:
    from skimage import filters
except ImportError:
    from skimage import filter as filters

# Init values
n = 2
img = Image.open("test.jpg")
data = np.array(img)
xlen = len(data[:,0])
ylen = len(data[0,:])

# Finds tha max and min value from the array
maxv = max(data.flatten())
minv = min(data.flatten())

# Data segmentation process
data = filters.gaussian(data, sigma = 1/n)
blobs = data > 0.8*(data.mean()) # Also play with this value
labels = measure.label(blobs)
setL = set(filter(lambda a : a !=0, labels.flatten()))
arrLab = []
lstPath=[]

# output dir
out_path = 'Segmentacion/'
if not os.path.isdir(out_path):
    os.makedirs(out_path)

# Binarization of the image
for i in range(1,len(setL),1):
    data2 = labels.astype('uint8')
    data2[data2 != i] = minv
    data2[data2 == i] = maxv
    arrLab.append(data2)

# Size limit Play with this value
limit = 100

# Write the value of the array
for ik in range(0,len(arrLab),1):
    ev = arrLab[ik]
    flat = list(filter(lambda a:a!=0,ev.flatten()))
    mide = len(flat)

    # If the image is smalled than the size of the image then wirte the image.
    if mide >= limit:
        lout = Image.fromarray(ev)
        lout.save(out_path + "Img_%s.png"%ik)
```

As **test.jpg** I used this image:

[image: input Image]

The result of these images inside the **Segmentacion** folder was:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I used this code to segment images of the corpus callosum obtained from MRIs.

Hopefully, this could help you and point you in the right direction!

Comment: playing with the values but it doesnot generate the output file

Comment: Give me some time, and I will add the actual code with the image that you uploaded.

Comment: I ran this same script that I posted in my computer with the results shown. What error are you finding?